# How can I direct stellar laboratory to my own instance of horizon?

Tags: horizon, stellar-laboratory, javascript-sdk

I cloned the [stellar laboratory](https://github.com/stellar/laboratory) project and edited the /src/constants/networks.js file to switch the testnet horizon url to url of my own horizon instance.

This allowed me to get requests such as checking account status, but post requests such as sending a transaction fail for "bad_auth", I figured out that this is because I didn't set my network passphrase, but I'm not sure where can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the solution, just write the password in the next line :)
In /src/constants/network.js

```
const NETWORK = {
  available: {
    test: {
      url: 'your url',
      networkObj: new Network('your passphrase'),
```